# How do I connect to a remote servers MySQL database using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Currently I have written a program to populate a mysql database on my own computer and I connect to it using JDBC using:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data?useSSL=false", "root", "your_new_password"); // MySQL

// Step 2: Allocate a 'Statement' object in the Connection
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();)
```

Now I need to populate the database of a remote server which I have been given a username and password to access. So I have the IP address of the the remote server, a username and password for the server. Once I have connected to the server, then I need to access the MySQL database on that server a root user and there is no password for root.

How do I connect to a remote MySQL server given the requirements above?

I have tried the following way:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:mysql://10.XXX.XX.XX:3306/data?useSSL=false", "serverusername", "serverpassword"); // MySQL
```

But I get the error:

> message from server: "Host 'Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
>                           "jdbc:mysql://10.143.38.63:3306/Adwhere2?useSSL=false", "serverusername", "serverpassword");' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server"

I have tried to connect to the server via ssh on the terminal, using the username and password and it successfully connected. So the username and password is not the problem.

I am able to access the server via ssh on the terminal using:
`ssh serverusername@10.XXX.XX.XX` , and then typing the password.

Once connected to the server I can connect the the mysql database using:

```
mysql -u root
```

Comment: Replace localhost by remote machine name.

Comment: if there is no password for that user did you try to specify no passowrd in connection string? From your question it is not clear enough what the problem is.

Comment: @atiqkhaled I tried that, but I get an error saying host is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Comment: Make sure you follow host credentials to access

Comment: @AlexeyR. my problem is I don't know how to connect to a remote server's database

Comment: It works exactly the same as connecting locally: specify the right hostname + port, and the username and password. I find it hard to believe you need to connect with root, when you have received a specific username and password. Note that you should post the full error message (+ stacktrace), based on what you commented you are not even connecting to MySQL, but to MariaDB, and the error suggests that the user you use doesn't have proper authorization to connect from its current hostname. Make sure its connect grants are correctly set.

Comment: @Programmer make sure that you're attempting to connect on a proper port. Port that is used to host the server on your machine may differ from a remote machine's port.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have added more detail to my question to clarify what the problem is

Comment: @AlexeyR. how do I find this port for the remote machine?

Comment: @Programmer you should ask database owner for the port. That person who communicated ip address to you.

Comment: is your machine allowed to access the DB? normally you have to grant access to external IP addresses in the DB

Comment: you need to allow remote connections to the database server, a remote connection is when the client have different hostname/IP address than the server, you can allow specific IP(s) or all IP(s) using `%` the command is i think the sql-query is `GRANT` which tells the server to grant access for the user `x` from host `y` or from any host `%`

Comment: That error means that your username is not allowed to connect from its current host. The database owner needs to grant your user access from your specific hostname or IP address, or give a blanket permission to connect from all hosts.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am able to access the server and database on the server, on the terminal. I am not sure how it translates to Java code

Comment: @yazan I can connect fine using the terminal

Comment: @PhilippSander yes I am, I added more details to my question to clarify

Comment: @AlexeyR. the owner said it will be the default mysql port, which I assume is 3306

Comment: it looks you have some misunderstanding, connecting using terminal that is running or connected to the server will be considered local connection not remote, because you are already connected to the machine via that SSH session, then you connect to db-server, in this case the connection from SSH to db-server is local, not remote...

Comment: can you access the DB from your machine WITHOUT ssh?! ssh is a useless indicator in this situation.

Comment: @PhilippSander I cannot

Comment: @Yazan, so how do I connect to the database?

Comment: well there's your issue. you are actually not allowed to acces the DB. the admin has to give you the permissions.